# Ocultar o deshabilitar contenido con display:none

Tags: javascript, java, html, bootstrap, jsp

Necesito ayuda estoy utilizando la propiedad `display:none` para ocultar o mostrar contenido según la opción que escoja, mi problema es que necesito bloquear o desabilitar automáticamente la otra opción o div que no seleccione, porque al momento de enviar los datos del formulario a otra página se envían x defecto los 2 valores, mi problema es que cuando escojo el `<div id="div1">`, automáticamente se envía el primer valor del select option del `<div id="div2">`

*esta es mi funcion de Js*

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#aula").click(function () {
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();

  });

  $("#sitio").click(function () {
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#div2").hide();

  });
});
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="display:none"> 
    <label for="Input" class="col-sm-12 control-label">INGRESE EL LUGAR EN LA QUE SE DARÁ LA TUTORIA</label>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lugar"  placeholder="Ingrese el Lugar">
    </div>
</div>
<%
    ResultSet rsAu = co.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT SZARPGN_CAMPVAR3 ||' - '||SZARPGN_CAMPVAR4 AS AULA, SZARPGN_CAMPVAR7 ||' - '||SZARPGN_CAMPVAR8 AS HORARIO, SZARPGN_CAMPVAR7 AS HORA_INICIO, SZARPGN_CAMPVAR8 AS HORA_FIN FROM SATURN.SZARPGN, SLBRDEF WHERE SZARPGN_IDREPORT = 'AULAS_'|| '" + campusd + "' AND SLBRDEF_BLDG_CODE = SZARPGN_CAMPVAR3 AND SLBRDEF_ROOM_NUMBER = SZARPGN_CAMPVAR4 AND SLBRDEF_RMST_CODE = 'AC' AND SLBRDEF_ROOM_TYPE = 'C' AND " + dia + " IS NOT NULL ORDER BY 3,4,1").executeQuery();
%>
<div id="div2" style="display:none" disabled>> 
    <label for="Input" class="col-sm-12 control-label">SELECIONE EL AULA Y EL HORARIO EN LA QUE SE DARÁ LA TUTORIA</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select class="form-control"  name="aula"id="Input">
            <% while (rsAu.next()) {%>
                <option>
                <% out.print(rsAu.getString("AULA") + " - " + rsAu.getString("HORA_INICIO") + " - " + rsAu.getString("HORA_FIN"));
                    }
                    rsAu.close();%>
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varias cosas, la primera, la solución a tu problema es que los `divs` no tienen un `id=sitio` ni id=`aula`.

En JQuery, cuando accedes a un elemento con la nomenclatura `$("#algo")` estas accediendo por medio de un identificador (`id`). Si lo haces con la nomenclatura `$(".algo")` estas accediendo por la clase (`class`). Y si lo haces con la nomenclatura `$("algo")` estas accediendo por el nombre de la etiqueta (`<tag/>`. Por ejemplo `$("div")`, accedería a todos los `divs`del documento `HTML`.

Ahora ya tema de diseño:

Es mejor separar estilos de HTML al menos que sea algo estrictamente necesario introducirlos. En tu caso creo que no te hace falta el: `style="display:none"` porque Jquery ya se encarga de mostrar y ocultar los elementos en tu JS.

Además, si le quitas eso no hace falta que hagas `.show` en el js, luego tu js quedaría más reducido:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#aula").click(function () {
    $("#div1").hide();
 });

 $("#sitio").click(function () {
    $("#div2").hide();
 });
```

});